# how to show html content for md-selected-item in md-autocomplete

Tags: angular-material, md-autocomplete

We are trying to use **md-autocomplete** in our application.  Things are working as expected, but we have a specific requirement for displaying the selected item.

Instead of just displaying a text, we need to display a HTML content with some avatar and formatted content.

**md-item-text** only displays any text provided, I tried the html content, but it does not work.

**md-item-template** works for the items displayed in the list, but the same styling is not applied to selected item.

Is there anyway to show the html content in Selected Item ?  Any suggestions ?